# springboot application deployment issue with WAS 8.5.5.12

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, websphere, java-9, websphere-8

I am trying to deploy a springboot application in was server 8.5.5.12., but facing an issue as application stops automatically after few seconds or does not start at all with following error:

```
11/29/19 2:18:39:584 CET] 0002c36e WSModuleDescr E   WSWS7011E: The configuration for the app-web.war application module cannot load correctly. 
The following error occurred:  com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationException: Annotation processing failed for class:  module-info.class
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationConfigReader.getAnnotationData(AnnotationConfigReader.java:883)
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationConfigReader.getAnnotationDataForZippedArchive(AnnotationConfigReader.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationConfigReader.getAnnotationData(AnnotationConfigReader.java:696)
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationConfigReader.populateModuleData(AnnotationConfigReader.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.MetaDataOrchestrator.getModuleData(MetaDataOrchestrator.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.annotations.collector.WASAnnotationCollector.getMDO(WASAnnotationCollector.java:258)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.annotations.collector.WASAnnotationCollector.collect(WASAnnotationCollector.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.getClassDataObjects(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:1458)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.initDBCMap(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:2153)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.buildJAXWSServiceRefs(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl._containsWebServiceClients(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.containsWebServiceClients(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.WSCacheWriter.writeModuleCache(WSCacheWriter.java:583)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.WSCacheWriter.writeApplicationCache(WSCacheWriter.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.WSCacheWriter.writeApplicationCache(WSCacheWriter.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.PersistentStorageInstallSaveTask.performTask(PersistentStorageInstallSaveTask.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1734)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$AppBinThread.run(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationConfigReader.getAnnotationData(AnnotationConfigReader.java:836)
    ... 18 more
```

the java compiler given in pom is 1.8.

```
<properties>
        <start-class>com.**</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <application.systemletters>CRAS</application.systemletters>
        <project.scm.id>java-group</project.scm.id>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- <springframework.boot.version>1.5.9.RELEASE</springframework.boot.version> -->
        <springframework.boot.version>1.5.18.RELEASE</springframework.boot.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.8</lombok.version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <sonar.skipDesign>true</sonar.skipDesign>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Added for SONAR unit test code coverage -->
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <!-- <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths> -->
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.verbose>true</sonar.verbose>
        <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
        <gson.version>2.8.2</gson.version>
        <!-- End -->

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.boot.version}</version>
            <!-- Excluding spring boot internal dependencies -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <!-- End -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added logback latest version -->
        <dependency> 
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId> 
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2.3</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.boot.version}</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.22.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.20.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.20.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAX-RS dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-configuration/commons-configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependencies for ESAPI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abnamro.cras</groupId>
            <artifactId>cras-commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.6.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sonatype.clm</groupId>
                <artifactId>clm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-01</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${jacoco.agent.ut.arg}</argLine>
                    <!-- Specific to generate mapping between tests and covered code -->
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>

                    <!-- test failure ignore -->
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any solution for the above error woud help. also how do we find out which dependencies is causing issue

Comment: Do you have webservices in your spring boot application? It seems that WAS is parsing some of the annotations.

Comment: yes , its a rest api

Comment: Oh i see there is a problem with module-info.class do you have Java >= 9 code anywhere?

Comment: we have jax.ws.rs dependency in it

Comment: no we dont have java>=9 , and we dont have java 9 compiler too as I checked

Comment: I expect it's this same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834667/there-is-annotationexception-when-try-to-deploy-ear-on-websphere-8-5-5-13