# Using websphere 9.0 i am unable to run the my server its coming an exception for maven project.what is the issue?

Tags: java, maven, server, websphere

I have added all the jars in pom.xml and added project to the server and i did update project and maven clean install aslo.for publishing it is taking so much time.
More than 400 seconds and not atlast illegal exception of this log4j is coming

```
 W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR unable to open input stream for resource META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class in archive WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.13.1.jar
                                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
        at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
        at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:120)
        at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJAR(ScannerContextImpl.java:275)
        at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJARs(ScannerContextImpl.java:315)
        at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.WARScannerContext.scanInternal(WARScannerContext.java:76)
        at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scan(ScannerContextImpl.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.getScannedClasses(ScannerContextImpl.java:70)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppCDIInjectionClassListCollaborator.getInjectionClasses(WebAppCDIInjectionClassListCollaborator.java:180)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsf.ext.JSFInjectionClassListCollaborator.getInjectionClasses(JSFInjectionClassListCollaborator.java:105)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.classic.CDIArchiveImpl.getInjectionClassList(CDIArchiveImpl.java:77)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.initializeJEEComponentClasses(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:349)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:281)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.scan(BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.weld.WebSphereCDIDeploymentImpl.scan(WebSphereCDIDeploymentImpl.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.impl.CDIContainerImpl.applicationStarting(CDIContainerImpl.java:117)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.classic.CDIRuntimeImpl.applicationStarting(CDIRuntimeImpl.java:323)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.classic.CDIRuntimeImpl.start(CDIRuntimeImpl.java:391)
        at com.ibm.ws.cdi.classic.CDIRuntimeImpl.stateChanged(CDIRuntimeImpl.java:488)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$ComparableDeployedObjectListener.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2551)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1164)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1497)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.setState(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:310)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1087)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:786)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2238)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5398)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5614)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2243)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is AnnotationException when try to deploy ear on websphere 8.5.5.13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834667/there-is-annotationexception-when-try-to-deploy-ear-on-websphere-8-5-5-13)

Comment: no mine is websphere 9.0

Comment: The APARS in the answer clearly apply to 9.0.